# MVC EditorFor Custom Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I am trying to create a custom helper for EditorFor. I want to take the string lengths from the models and add this to the html attributes.

I have the following so far but this doesnt apply the new attributes that are added.

```
    public static IHtmlString MyEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object ViewData, bool disabled = false, bool visible = true)
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var stringLength = member.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as StringLengthAttribute;

        RouteValueDictionary viewData =  HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData);
        RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(viewData["htmlAttributes"]);

        if (stringLength != null)
        {
            htmlAttributes.Add("maxlength", stringLength.MaximumLength);
        }

        return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression, ViewData);
    }
```

Comment: `return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression, ViewData)` is not adding any attributes. Its just using the original `ViewData` attribute you passed to the method

Comment: How can I edit that and return the attributes? I am unable to return the new viewData object as it is a different type

Answer (score 1):

You're returning original `ViewData` attribute in method parameter instead of custom HTML attributes collection on `return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression, ViewData)`. Based from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225652/6378815), your return method should changed to this:

```
public static IHtmlString MyEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object ViewData, bool disabled = false, bool visible = true)
{
    var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    var stringLength = member.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as StringLengthAttribute;

    RouteValueDictionary viewData =  HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData);
    RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(viewData["htmlAttributes"]);

    if (stringLength != null)
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("maxlength", stringLength.MaximumLength);
    }

    return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression, htmlAttributes); // use custom HTML attributes here
}
```

Then, apply custom HTML helper on view side like this:

```
@Html.MyEditorFor(model => model.Property, new { htmlAttributes = new { @maxlength = "10" }})
```

**Edit**:

This method works on MVC 5 (5.1) and above, I can't sure it works in earlier versions (refer this question: [Html attributes for EditorFor() in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735400/html-attributes-for-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc)).

For earlier MVC versions, usage of `HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor` is more preferred, which certainly has `maxlength` attribute:

```
return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
```

Additional references:

[Set the class attribute to Html.EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC Razor View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559028/set-the-class-attribute-to-html-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view)

[HTML.EditorFor adding class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926236/html-editorfor-adding-class-not-working)

Comment: The `EditorFor()` method does not accept html attributes in its 2nd parameter